# Gettting Unable to determine the provider name for connection with MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, mysql-connector

I am working with ASP.NET MVC4 and I am trying to move my data access layer to a separate project. Each user on my site gets their own database so I need to specify a different database in the connection string for each user. The way I am currently doing this is:

```
public TableDbContext GetTableDbContextForUser(string userName)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(getUserConnectionString(userName));
    return new MySqlTableDbContext(connection);
}

private string getUserConnectionString(string userName)
{
    ConnectionStringSettings csSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"];

    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(csSettings.ConnectionString);
    csBuilder.Database += "_" + userName;

    return csBuilder.GetConnectionString(true);
}
```

And my constructor:

```
public MySqlTableDbContext(MySqlConnection connection)
    : base(connection, false) //Inherits from DbContext
{ }
```

And finally my connection string (this is in Web.config in my main project and App.config in my database project):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=cybercomm;password=*;DefaultCommandTimeout=0;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

MySqlTableDbContext is in my Database project and I am trying to use it in my main project. It gets created just fine however when I call any method through it I get the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233067
Message=Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at EPSCoR.Web.Database.Context.MySqlTableDbContext.DropTable(String table) in c:\Users\Devin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EPSCoR\Web\Database\Context\MySqlTableDbContext.cs:line 110
   at EPSCoR.Web.App.Repositories.Basic.BasicTableRepo.Drop(String tableName) in c:\Users\Devin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EPSCoR\Web\App\Repositories\Basic\BasicTableRepo.cs:line 71
   at EPSCoR.Web.App.Controllers.TableIndexController.Delete(Int32 id) in c:\Users\Devin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EPSCoR\Web\App\Controllers\ModelController.cs:line 172
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

I know that my connection string works because when I pass DbContext the connection name ("MySqlConnection") in the constructor I can update and create models. Its only when I try to change the database parameter in the string that it breaks. Also this worked when everything was in one project, so I know that this should work somehow.

Is there anything I am missing here?

In case it might help I have MySql.Data v6.7.4.0 and EF v5 installed through nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this worked but I reinstalled both the EntityFramework and MySql.Data packages and then everything started working again.